# Add a verification email address for new users only in WooCommerce checkout

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, checkout, email-validation

I want to add an email address verification field to WooCommerce checkout page, but only for new users. So, if a user is already logged in, it should not ask them for the verification email address field.

I have added this code to my functions.php and it works great. It asks for the email address, but it's also doing it for already logged in users.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_fields', 'bbloomer_add_email_verification_field_checkout' );

function bbloomer_add_email_verification_field_checkout( $fields ) {

    $fields['billing']['billing_email']['class'] = array('form-row-first');

    $fields['billing']['billing_em_ver'] = array(
        'label'     => __('Email Address Verification', 'bbloomer'),
        'required'  => true,
        'class'     => array('form-row-last'),
    'clear'     => true
    );

    return $fields;
}

// ---------------------------------
// 3) Generate error message if field values are different

add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_process', 'bbloomer_matching_email_addresses' );
function bbloomer_matching_email_addresses() { 
    $email1 = $_POST['billing_email'];
    $email2 = $_POST['billing_em_ver'];
    if ( $email2 !== $email1 ) {
        wc_add_notice( __( 'Your email addresses do not match', 'bbloomer' ), 
 'error' );
    }
}
```

How to make that field only to be only displayed for non logged in users?

Comment: How about using [is_user_logged_in()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_user_logged_in/)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have made some changes in your code and added the necessary condition to make it work for non logged in users only:

```
// Add or change Woocommerce Checkout fields
add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_fields', 'add_billing_email_check_field', 20, 1 );
function add_billing_email_check_field( $fields ) {
    // Only for non logged in users
    if( is_user_logged_in() ) return $fields;

    $fields['billing']['billing_email']['class'] = array('form-row-first');

    $fields['billing']['billing_email_check'] = array(
        'label'     => __('Email Address Verification', 'woocommerce'),
        'required'  => true,
        'class'     => array('form-row-last'),
        'clear'     => true
    );

    return $fields;
}

// Billing email validation check error message
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_process', 'billing_email_validation_check' );
function billing_email_validation_check() {
    if ( isset( $_POST['billing_email'] ) && isset( $_POST['billing_email_check'] ) &&
        $_POST['billing_email'] !== $_POST['billing_email_check'] )
        wc_add_notice( __( 'Your <strong>billing email address</strong> does not match.', 'woocommerce' ), 'error' );
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and work.

Comment: Worked! Thank you!